# How do I Batch Rename Folders in OSX?

Tags: macos, automator

So I have been trying to rename about 5000 folders based on a CSV (Old name, Newname)

This is a one time operation, once hdkjsh2-2f8c-46b9-bbdb_doc is converted to 3 then it will not need to be touched again.

I have tried the solution [here (Setting up an automator workflow with a command script)](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/automater-workflow-rename-from-csv-small-problem.2030795/) but found that it does not do a great deal when it comes to folder/directory names and all the guides/documentation is around file names and not folder. 
Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Example of CSV

```
Doc_Location,  New_ID
hdkjsh2-2f8c-46b9-bbdb_doc , 3
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a few lines from your CSV so we can see how it is delimited. Also, are the names in there in the correct order - what I mean is might you rename directory `bill` as `fred` and then at some later point, rename `bill/mary` as something else but will now no longer work because `bill` is now `fred` from the first step. Also, are there spaces in the directory names?

Comment: It doesn't encourage people to answer your questions when they are poorly formatted, inconsistent within themselves and you don't clarify questions... You say the CSV is *"Old name, Newname"* whereas it is actually *"New name, Old name"*. I have reformatted the CSV properly. You did not answer either my question about spaces, or order of renaming. Nobody will want to spend ages working out an answer only to be told *"Sorry, I explained it wrong"*.

Comment: This is a one time operation, once hdkjsh2-2f8c-46b9-bbdb_doc is converted to 3 then it will not need to be touched again, so no needs to worry about order. As for spaces no there are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please make a backup before trying the following.**

Save the following script in your `HOME` directory as `renamer`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat "file.csv" | while IFS=' ,' read dir new ; do
   if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
      echo Rename $dir as $new
      #mv "$dir" "$new"
   else
      echo "ERROR: Directory $dir not found - ignored"
   fi
done
```

Then start Terminal and make the script executable by running:

```
chmod +x $HOME/renamer
```

Then change directory to where your directories are that need renaming:

```
cd path/to/things/needing/renaming
```

Make sure you have your CSV, called `file.csv` saved in that directory, then run with:

```
$HOME/renamer
```

It doesn't actually do anything, it just tells you what it would do. If it looks correct, edit `$HOME/renamer` and remove the single `#` on the line that says:

```
#mv "$dir" "$new"
```

so that is looks like:

```
mv "$dir" "$new"
```

Then be doubly sure you have made a backup and run the script again:

```
$HOME/renamer
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder where the other folders you want to rename are located. Select all the folders you want to rename. Then click on the action icon at the top of finder window. This will open a window where one option is to rename x items. See image below.

[image]

When you select "Rename x items" you get a box like the one shown below where you can specify the new names.

[image]

Comment: Looking at about 5000~ folders to be converted out of 10k+ so not really an option

Comment: is there a way to sort them so that the 5000 are listed together? Then you can select them all

Comment: If the name of the 5000 are similar then maybe the mv command may work,  you can do  mv oldfilename0001 newfilename0001 , for example.

Comment: Great feature of the Finder I didn't know before.